# Why lambda and not local functions?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I can't understand why complex lambdas syntax were added into 'C++11' instead of just allowing local functions to be defined. In other words why this:

```
int main()
{
    auto lambda = []() { };
}
```

And not this:

```
int main()
{
    void lambda() { }
}
```

I can guess you'll point out that it's because local functions won't be usable in expressions but that wouldn't be exactly true as syntax supporting this form could be easily added very intuitively by just enabling temporary functions. Something like this:

```
int main()
{
    void func(auto callable) ;

    func( (void ()) { } ); //here we are basically creating a temporary of function type
}
```

OK. Let's say we were to specify capturing by either value or reference this way (very similar to current lambda's):

[*capture-list*] *function-declaration*

As capture list will be with exactly the same semantics as described [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

So it'll look at practice like this:

```
int main()
{
    int tmp;

    void func(auto callable) ;

    func( ([tmp]void ()) { } ); //here 'tmp' is captured by value

    [&] void func1() { } //here all locals are captured by reference

    void func2() { } //same as above
}
```

But still it'll be a function-definition and not an object one.

Do note that `void func(auto callable)` is not a lambda function but a declaration of global one. Only when it is defined into another function it became lambda.

Just to give a working example demonstrating that this is actually possible to be implemented I'll use GCC 'C' which support similar syntax by extension:

Life [Example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/xbJGhC89iZZ0h9kJ).

Comment: I suppose local functions would lack closures.

Comment: What do you exactly mean? They'll capture all local variables currently accessible from the point of definition. Actually this is already implemented as an extension in GCC 'C' frontend.

Comment: @FISOCPP so they would capture all local variables previously defined by default?

Comment: @FISOCPP: By value or by reference?

Comment: I suppose by reference it will be best - this way it's implemented by GCC 'C' extension and it actually feels most intuitive. But this could be decided. I'm asking why it wasn't and alternative syntax were provided.

Comment: @FISOCPP You need to be able to choose, was his point.

Comment: @FISOCPP: Unless the function object needs to outlive the local variables. You need the choice between capturing by reference and value, and hence a lambda-like syntax.

Comment: @FISOCPP If you're asking why the language designers decided on this syntax instead of something that looks more like a regular function, it wasn't just for the hell of it. It's extremely hard to add any new syntax in the language which doesn't break old syntax, and they are unwilling to break backwards compatibility. The syntax you're proposing definitely screws up existing syntax for variable declarations and for function _type_ syntax.

Comment: Actually I can't exactly see what old syntax would be broken as local functions are forbidden anyway as well as function temporaries.

Comment: "Why would they choose the current syntax, and not some syntax which I will not fully specify but only vaguely describe?"  Adding things to C++ is a technical issue.  If you don't give technical details in your proposal, including exact syntax, showing what goes wrong is very difficult, as you are free to randomly permute "what you mean" whenever an issue arises.  If your question was more concrete, we could point out problems: but you want **everything** that could go wrong with **any** other syntax, which seems a bit too broad.

Comment: What can't you exactly understand about it? Local functions by their syntax express best what lambda's actually does.

Comment: Lambdas have more functionality than local functions. If you change how local functions work so that they match the functionality of a lambda, then they would no longer be local functions they would be lambdas. I suspect if `C` had class member functions they might have gone for full blown lambda's too.

Comment: You did not describe how to partially capture, capture by value, or any kind of formal grammar so we could find ambiguities.  If you gave an actual SPECIFIC "wouldn't this be better", it would be one thing, but people have come up with many flaws in your design.  Your response is "well, add something *waves hands* to make it work".  You are asking "why not anything even vaguely like this".  This requires people answering your question not only come up with a myriad of solutions to flaws in your proposal, but also show that EVERY possible solution to EVERY flaw cannot be surmounted.

Comment: OK - done. I added a syntax for specifying it. Check my OP.

Comment: Now it just becomes a debate about syntax. The question boils down to "Why did they choose this syntax and not that syntax?".

Comment: Yeah - that's right. This way we make a use of an currently forbidden syntax and not add entirely new one. And as a benefit currently 'GCC' C code using it's nested functions extensions will have a chance to compile under C++.

Comment: Why this question was put on hold? I really can't see. It's asking a very clear question. What opinion is shown?

Comment: So now `[tmp]void () { /* code */` is a temporary function returning `void` that takes no arguments.  As opposed to `[tmp]{ /* code */ }` or `[tmp]()->void{/*code*/}` in current C++. Can you omit the `void()` in your syntax?  Is `void func(auto callable);` also a lambda?  It better not be: that is syntax to declare the interface of a function from the enclosing scope.  So this only happens when you replace the `;` with `{ /* code */}`?  What kind of "thing" is `func1`?  Identical to `auto func1=[&]{ /*code*/ };`?

Comment: And is your only objection to lambda is that the return value type comes *after* the `()`s?  In your syntax, can you omit that return value type?  Or is it just you want `void foo() { blah }` to be equivalent to `auto foo = [&]{ blah };`, and consider other uses of lambda secondary?

Comment: My objection is to the whole idea. Currently lambda creates some unknown object with methods and etc. which is kinda complex. By using the syntax proposed - it'll be just a special definition of a normal function which will also cover the illegal syntax of defining local one. About 
    'void func(auto callable);'
 - yeah it will be a declaration of function from the global scope - only when a function is defined in another function it will became lambda. We could resolve which one will be called by using '::' prefix for accessing global namespace.

Comment: @FISOCPP So the primary differences between your *perfect* syntax and what we have today are the trailing return type and where the name of a lambda would go, meaning instead of `auto foo = []{};` you prefer `void foo(){}`. Trailing return types were needed regardless of lambdas, and can be used for any functions so your proposed syntax would have to allow for them too. Once you discard that, I don't see what benefit your syntax has. Also consider that I can return a lambda from a function, but returning a function from a function is illegal, so should that rule be altered too?

Comment: You can return a reference or pointer to one however. It has the benefit that it support a very intuitive way of defining a lambda as a local function. This is it mainly. I never said it was perfect - my question was why the current syntax and not this one - because local functions are far more close to the idea of lambdas.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple reasons:

- Lambdas provide syntax for 'capturing' - you can capture by value or reference, move into a capture argument, name capture arguments, etc
- The syntax `sometype func{}` within a function creates a default constructed variable named func of type `sometype` - and would therefore be quite ambiguous about whether you want a function or variable
- Lambdas are *usually* closer to shorthand for a functor than shorthand for a function (any time there is a capture)

Comment: I already provided an alternate for it. About the second reason well - then why there isn't ambiguity between global function definition and global variable initialization - I smell you understand something wrong. For the third reason - I can tell that similarly 'virtual' functions are close to member function references but AFAIK are still functions ;).

Answer (score 2):

Lambdas provide a syntax for choosing which variables to capture, and how to capture them. A local function wouldn't, making it rather less useful.

Also, lambdas are expressions, allowing you to define simple functions at the point of use without requiring a separate declaration.

Comment: For the first - I'm sure we could somehow extend the local function definition syntax to allow us specify this information. And for the second - I already gave an alternative by using a concept temporary functions.

Comment: @FISOCPP: By making those changes to the function syntax, you get a lambda. Which is why we have lambdas.

Comment: Not exactly. It will be still a function definition and thus it will allow currently forbidden syntax instead of adding new one.

Comment: @FISOCPP: So I guess your question is really, why don't we have local functions *in addition to* lambdas - since we need something other than a function (and exactly like a lambda) to allow these two things. To which the answer is presumably that, given the existence of lambdas to achieve the same effect, it wasn't worth the effort of adding them to the standard.

Comment: I can't clearly see why 'we need something other than a function (and exactly like a lambda) to allow these two things'?

Comment: @FISOCPP: It needs to be a class type (or similar), not a function, to allow capturing. It needs to be specified by an expression, not a declaration, to allow the creation of temporaries. Those changes make it exactly like a lambda.

Comment: I don't think so. 'Virtual' functions similarly need to be references in order to work properly but are actually defined as functions. Core language does a lot of magic you know. About the creation of temporaries - I already suggested the alternate syntax.

Comment: @FISOCPP: It can't be declared just like a function: you need the two syntactic extensions I keep describing, to allow capture specifications and to use it as an expression. Your syntax for temporaries is almost exactly the same as a lambda's, just with a leading return type instead of an optional trailing one. So the only questions are, why are the exact details of the syntax slightly different from yours, and why didn't they also add local functions declared with traditional syntax in addition to lambdas? Neither of which are particularly interesting.

Comment: But this is not a reason to put my question on hold as opinion based. The question is very clear and I'm sure there should be some not opinion base explanation.

Comment: @FISOCPP: Which is why I answered it, and didn't vote to close it.